# Create my own pop3 account without @domain.com in username

Tags: email, pop3, mail-server

I need a pop3 email account setup that does not have the @domain.com in the username. It's for a piece of software that I am using that does not like seeing @domain.com in the username for setup. Any idea's? The account only needs to be accessed locally.

Comment: what operating system(s) are you using?  by "locally" do you mean "on the same LAN" or "on the same computer"?

Comment: Using windows xp. On the same computer will be fine for now. I am using a clumsy piece of software that needs to have data inputted by pop3 email.

Comment: Before starting to look at solutions that involve you changing mail providers, I would personally take a look at the software documentation or ask the developers (or tell us the software and someone may be able to help). It may be as simply as putting brackets, quotes or an escape character of some sorts before the at symbol or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Gmail](https://mail.google.com/mail/)** supports POP3 logins without the domain part. *(Except for Google Apps users, of course.)*

---

If your "clumsy piece of software" does not support SSL encryption either, this can be handled by [stunnel](http://stunnel.mirt.net/) in client mode:

```
[gmail-pop3]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:1234
connect = pop.gmail.com:995
```

Comment: I think this may be the problem. I tried Gmail and still no dice. I will give stunnel a go tomorrow and see what happens. I will post a reply once I try it.

Comment: Still no dice. I copied and pasted your code above into the stunnels .conf file and still have not had any success.

Comment: @Richard: Did you not forget to start stunnel and change your program's settings to use 127.0.0.1 port 1234 as the POP3 server?

Comment: I did and it is started. I will check with the software manufacture and see what is going on. When or if they get back to me I will let the forum know.